# View a dashboard or wrokbook via azure app on phone

Tags: azure

I know this is a really silly question but seem unable to view dashboards via the azure app. I seem to be able only to view the recourse it sits in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! As of now, we cannot view the dashboard in Azure Mobile Application. Whatever the applications pin to the dashboard and Favorites sections are only visible to the Desktop Browser Application.

[image: AzureMobileApp]

I have pinned few applications to the Dashboard and published it in my Azure Subscription, but it shown the details of that dashboard, provisioning, update details but not the resources in that dashboard.

[image: AzureMobileAppDashboardexploring]

As compared to its web-based Azure Portal Counterpart, Mobile App has limited in functionality as of now. I would recommend using the base Azure Portal on your PC.

To raise this feature as feature request, mail the details to `azureapp@microsoft.com`.